# Possible to pass a list of integer through web api or do I have to use a string param

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a scenario where I need to send multiple ProductIds in a GET Request to my Web API.

In my asp.net web api controller is there a way that I can make the param of my Action method be of type `List<int> productIds`. I am assuming no, I have to pass them like this ?ProductIds=1,2,3 and then accept it as `string productIds`.

Please let me know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indicate that you are going to be accepting an `int[]` as your parameter and Web API should handle mapping the comma-delimited string to an array as expected. You may need to include the `[FromUri]` attribute to let Web API know that you are expecting these values from the querystring :

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts([FromUri] int[] ProductIds)
{
      // Your code here.
}
```

You could also indicate that multiple values are mapped to the same querystring parameter via :

```
?ProductIds=1&ProductIds=2&ProductIds=3...
```

Comment: Ok so what should my query string param look like and what should the param in my Action Method look like? Additionally does it have to be an array? Can I use list?

Comment: The comma-delimited string approach that you are using should work just fine or you could use the second approach that I provided (i.e. repeated querystring parameters). [Filip Woj has a blog post](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/) on this topic that goes into a bit more detail and even uses a custom binder to handle comma-delimited values.

Comment: Do you know why if I don't pass the param at all the list is coming in as instantiated with a count of 0? I expect it to be null.

Comment: I have the param like: List<int> productIds = null

Comment: Will `[FromUri]` help in transferring a lots of data, like list of 1000 items, will it not be cumbersome sending it

Comment: This does not work for a comma separated list as described.